# What is the absolute minimum cumulative weight that a transaction must have to be considered confirmed by a vendor?

Tags: security, double-spending, documentation

I assume that referencing a Milestone is not sufficient for a vendor (exchange). That is, they must be making sure that both a Milestone is referenced AND that some time or cumulative weight threshold is acheived.

Given that, what is the absolute minimum cumulative weight that a transaction must have to be considered confirmed by a vendor?

What are the IOTA Foundation's official recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There are no recommendations out yet, because we still need the coo to prevent double spends.

In the whitepaper it stats that the confirmation status of a transaction is given by the percentage of tips that directly or indirectly reference this transaction (http://iotatoken.com/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf Page 3). If we select 100 random tips and 70% of them indirectly reference our transaction, it is 70% confirmed.

However, it is unclear how the coo will be removed/decentralized. Depending on how confirmations are defined in the future we will get some recommendations for sure.

Comment: At the moment, the coo is deciding if a transaction is confirmed or not.